# problem getting the right outcome with foreach

Tags: php, indexing, foreach

I have the following code to generate a HTML table with the placed orders.

```
// Select data FROM ORDER & ORDERLINE
        $id = $value->ID;
        $datenow = date("Y-m-d");
        $temp = 0;
        $stmt2 = $mysql->prepare("SELECT salesorder.order_id AS soid, salesorder.delivery_date AS sdd, orderline.qty AS olq, food.food_type AS fft
                                FROM orderline
                                INNER JOIN salesorder ON salesorder.order_id = orderline.order_id
                                INNER JOIN food ON food.food_id = orderline.food_id
                                WHERE salesorder.client_id=? AND orderline.qty!=?
                                ORDER BY sdd");
        $stmt2->bind_param('ss', $id, $temp);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $result2 = $stmt2->get_result();
        
    // determen if there are orders to display
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
        
        while ($value2 = $result2->fetch_object()) {
        $results[] = $value2; 
        }
    ?>

    <table class="center table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Order Number</th>
                    <th>Delivery Date</th>
                    <th>QTY</th>
                    <th>Food Type</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <b>Delivered orders :</b> (and orders delivered today...)
                <?php foreach ( $results as $result ) : ?>
                <?php if (($result->sdd)<=$datenow) { ?>
                        <td><?php echo ($result->soid); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo ($result->sdd); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo ($result->olq); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo ($result->fft); ?></td>                      
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The problem is that the 'delivery date' and 'order number' ALSO are displayed as many times as there are QTY and food types. i know this has to do with indexes, but however i try, i cant find the right syntax or way to do it. Any ideas?
I have added the data tables as images. Please let me know...

Comment: First of all, please stop creating invalid HTML. You can not just put a `b` into `tbody` directly like that.

Comment: _“i know this has to do with indexes”_ - no, it doesn’t, if anything, this has to do with what _type_ of JOIN you are using. INNER JOINs are probably now what you want here.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample of the data for the 3 tables orderline, salesorder, and food?

Comment: i have inserted a picture with the 3 tables

Comment: What have you tried to check for problems? Why not start with inspecting the SQL query - copy it, paste it to phpMyAdmin or whatever you use, and check if the data returned is the data you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments on the other answer by Eibs please could you check if the following gives you what you need. First when you are looping the results we create an associative array grouped by the order number and date and add each item to the items array. Then when creating the table we loop the results array and then the items array. I have used separate rows only because you have a headings row, however, using this same approach you can design your table output a number of different ways.

```
  // determen if there are orders to display
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0)
  {
    while($value2 = $result2->fetch_object())
    {
      $key = $value2->soid.'-'.$value2->sdd;
      if(!isset($results[$key]))
      {
        $results[$key] = array(
            'soid' => $value2->soid,
            'sdd' => $value2->sdd,
            'items' => array(),
        );
      }
      $results[$key]['items'][] = $value2;
    }
  }
  ?>
  <table class="center table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Order Number</th>
      <th>Delivery Date</th>
      <th>QTY</th>
      <th>Food Type</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><b>Delivered orders :</b> (and orders delivered today...)</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($results as $result) : ?>
      <?php if($result['sdd'] <= $datenow): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo($result['soid']); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo($result['sdd']); ?></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($result['items'] as $item): ?>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo($item->olq); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo($item->fft); ?></td>
          </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Hi Mark. That indeed did the trick. Thank you so much. i knew it was something with index, but i am still very fresh with PHP. Again Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Inside of `foreach` u need to open `<tr>` Tag
2. You Can Loop the array directly `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returning array, then why you store into `$results[]` array,

Comment: sorry my mistake, you use fetch_object(), msyqli_fetch_assoc and fetch_objec() return same thing, in your case:
<?php while ($value2 = $result2->fetch_object()) { ?>
        <?php if (($value2 ->sdd)<=$datenow) { ?>
                   <tr>
                        <td><?php echo ($value2 ->soid); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo ($value2 ->sdd); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo ($value2 ->olq); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo ($value2 ->fft); ?></td>                      
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
 <?php } ?>

Comment: Like above comment, you can use the fetch_object return array, so you don't need to push the return array into $results2 array, and after use that on foreach

Comment: Thanks Eibs, indeed double up. but my actual problem remains, that i see in the result, ordernumber and delivery date also repeated 4 times, as much as i have qty and food type. the result i would like is a table with the order number, delivery daye, and the n multiple rows with the qty's and food types

Comment: did your query running perfectly on database by your need?

Comment: outcome of query looks good, however it loops through everything, and each line gives order number, date, qty and food type. what i want is order number and date once, and then the qty and food-type as many as there are